# How can ı get probability values for each class with predict method on an A.N.N model on Keras

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I'm new on the deep learning subjects, i need help for getting individual probabilities for each class on a Keras artificial neural network(A.N.N.) model.I have an exoplanet catalog dataset from PHL and i'm trying to make predictions according to whether planet is habitable, maybe habitable or not habitable.For now i have tried A.N.N. with some important columns like

```
dataToLearn = data[["P_DISTANCE","S_HZ_OPT_MIN", "S_HZ_OPT_MAX", "S_HZ_CON_MIN", "S_HZ_CON_MAX", "P_TYPE", "P_ESI", "P_HABITABLE"]]
class_names = list(dataToLearn.columns)
```

ı got rid of some 'nan' values with,

```
dataToLearn = dataToLearn.dropna(how='all')
dataToLearn = dataToLearn.dropna(subset=['P_TYPE', 'P_ESI'])
```

then preprocessed the data,

```
labelencoder_pType = LabelEncoder()
dataToLearn["P_TYPE"] = labelencoder_pType.fit_transform(dataToLearn["P_TYPE"])
onehotencoder = ColumnTransformer([("P_TYPE", OneHotEncoder(),[5])], remainder = "passthrough")
dataToLearn = onehotencoder.fit_transform(dataToLearn)
#Dummy Variable Trap
dataToLearn = dataToLearn[:,1:]
dataToLearn = pd.DataFrame(dataToLearn)

X = dataToLearn.iloc[:,:10].values
Y = dataToLearn.iloc[:,10].values
Y = pd.get_dummies(Y).values
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size = 0.35)
y_test = y_test.astype(np.float64)
y_train = y_train.astype(np.float64)
sc_X = ColumnTransformer([("",StandardScaler(),slice(0,10))])
x_train = sc_X.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = sc_X.transform(x_test)
```

as you can see ı have hot-encoded the output(Y) values but i'm not sure do i need to do that in multiclass problems.On next step i built the classifier like below.

```
def build_classifier():
    classifier = Sequential() # initialize neural network
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 10, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = x_train.shape[1]))
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 8, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
    classifier.add(Dropout(0.3))
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 8, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
    classifier.add(Dropout(0.3))
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 3, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'softmax'))
    classifier.compile(optimizer = 'RMSprop', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
return classifier
classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn = build_classifier, batch_size = 32, epochs = 150)
accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator = classifier, X = x_train, y = y_train, cv = 10, n_jobs = -1)
accuracyMean = accuracies.mean()
classifier.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Then predicted the x_test with

```
y_pred = classifier.predict(x_test)
```

The problem is i cannot get predicted array(y_pred) with the same dimension as y_test which is one-hot encoded according to three possibilities.In y_pred i'm always getting 0(not habitable) or 2(may habitable) results and never 1(habitable) but in one column shape, i think the reason of the model's failure on predicting the 1(habitable) case comes from the rarity of this case in dataset.But i still don't know why y_pred is in one column shape and i can't find a good explanation on how to do multi-class classification on with keras A.N.N on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try adding class_weight, assign high weight to class 1

```
class_weight = {0: 1.,
                1: 50.,
                2: 2.}

classifier.fit(x_train, y_train, clf__class_weight = class_weight)
```

2. To get the class probability with Keras Sequential model

```
y_pred = classifier.predict_proba(x_test)
```

Comment: For class_weight it raises an error like:                                                                     
      ValueError: class_weigth is not a legal parameter

Comment: That's strange, according to documentation this should work. Try to use this in the fit function as I updated and let me know.

Comment: I guess it's used in fit function but now that throwed another error: TypeError: Unrecognized keyword arguments: {'class_weigth': {0: 1.0, 1: 50.0, 2: 2.0}}

Comment: What is your keras version? Try clf__class_weight as I updated and check please.

Comment: My keras version: 2.3.1 and sorry guess i couldn't understand usage of clf__class_weigth should ı change the class_weight dictionary's name or parameter name in the fit function, tried that last thing ı wrote but didn't work.

Comment: Wait, your first error says 'class_weigth' <- it's spelled wrong. Are you sure you have typed everything right?

Comment: I checked it so many times but i'm sure that is correct. Isn't  'class_weigth' spelled that way or i'm getting crazy :)

Comment: Nope, copy my code, `classifier.fit(x_train, y_train, class_weight = class_weight)`

Comment: Great. That's why it's always useful to add the error log to the question in bold, I was weirded out as the error was very unlikely.